# How can I let my site provide smart answers in the Chrome omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome, suggestions

Chrome 69 now shows rich answers directly in the Omnibox ([source](https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/chromes-turning-10-heres-whats-new/)) without the user having to load a new tab.

[image]

Is there a way to encourage Google to use specific data in the Omnibox? So if I'm building a new site can I use microdata that will be used to display to users?

Comment: The Omnibox is complex and more than just microdata. It's AI capable and is results will vary from one user to the next based on usage, its early days to say what influences it, but looking at top results are just favicon, top image and description.

Comment: From your example, it looks like it's pulling similar information to what we currently see in "[featured snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en-GB)" and "definitions" that are returned at the top of the SERPs (albeit far more condensed). We have no control over "featured snippets" (except for "opting out") and I suspect we'll have no control over this feature either. Google using its ever impressive AI I expect.

Comment: "Chrome 69 now shows rich answers" - Specifically, which version of Chrome 69 are you seeing this? (Or is this "reported"). I'm using Chrome 69, but I'm not seeing any "rich answers"?